# Updating datatable with check boxes using primefaces datatable and seam

Tags: java, primefaces, seam

Hey guys I'm pretty new to primefaces and seam. Any answers would be very much appreciated.

I have a commandbutton when clicked is supposed to add a new record in the database update my backing bean and update my datatable that is seen by the client.
Problem is I get this error whenever I click my button:

Exception during request processing:
Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message: "" 
(it doesn't even say what error I have)

My commandbutton is declared like this: (in my xhtml file)

and my datatable is declared like this:

```
                        </p:outputPanel>
```

dont know what i missed.. Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Check your question, you are missing some info, no?